# Search in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, php, json, livesearch

I'm perform a live 
I use this to get the json file

```
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
  while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
        $output["name"][]=$row1["name"];
        $output["email"][]=$row1["email"];
  }
}

$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp,json_encode($output));
fclose($fp);
?>
```

and i got something like this in the json file

```
{
"name":["Marinasy","test","test","Nath"],
"email":["behambymarinasy@gmail.com","test@test","test@trs","nath@trs"]
}
```

But I need something like the code below to do a search. Is there any way to get a JSON like this instead of the JSON above?
or how I do search in the code above?

```
[
  {
    "name":"Marinasy",
    "email": "behambymarinasy@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "name":"Test",
    "email": "test@test"

  },
  {
    "name":"Nath",
    "email": "nath@trs"
  }
]
```

Comment: bruh, hide yo real info

Comment: Where does the `email` key get generated?

Comment: $output["name"][]=$row1["name"];
$output["email"][]=$row1["email"];

Comment: Question. You're generating this JSON file from data in the database. Why not search the database? I would normally assume it was because you're sending it to a third party, but not sure in this case.

Comment: I've tried to search in database but I didn't know how to add link on the result that's why i use json

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What do you mean `add link on the result`?

Comment: this for a chat application ,, I created a "New message" function doing a live search from contact and user can click the result

Comment: sorry i'm not verry good in english speaking but i try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
$output["name"][]=$row1["name"];
$output["email"][]=$row1["email"];
```

to

```
$output[] = [
    "name"=>$row1["name"],
    "email"=>$row1["email"]
];
```

Full code here

```
<?php
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $output = [];
        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $output[] = [
                "name" => $row1["name"],
                "email" => $row1["email"]
            ];
        }
    }

    $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($output));
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this...

```
<?php
$output= array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
  while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
        array_push($output, array('name'=> $row1["name"], 'email'=> $row1["email"]));
  }
}

$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp,json_encode($output));
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: solved.. thank you so much  i didn'sleep 'cause of this